# Construir uma matriz através de um vetor

Tags: c, matriz, array, operadores, scanf

Eu coloco nove dígitos no vetor mas minha matriz sai com números aleatórios, eu gostaria que minha matriz saísse com os números que estão no vetor segue a baixo meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int vetor [9];
int matriz [3][3];
int i=0, lin=0, col=0, k=0;

main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    printf("Digite 9 número para uma matriz \n" );
    for(i=0;i<9;i++){
        scanf("%i", &vetor[i]);
    }
    for(lin=0;lin<3;lin++){
        for(col=0;col<3;col++){
            matriz[lin][col] = vetor[k];
            k++;
            printf("%i\t", &matriz[lin][col]);
        }printf("\n");
}
}
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O principal motivo do problema é que está pegando o endereço do matriz para imprimir. Então para resolver é só tirar o operador `&` no argumento do `printf()`. O operador é necessário no `scanf()` apenas para passar uma referência, na impressão isto não é necessário, então o parâmetro não está esperando uma. Dei uma melhorada geral, mas dá para evitar o laço aninhado também, preferi não mexer demais para dificultar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int vetor [9];
    int matriz [3][3];
    printf("Digite 9 número para uma matriz \n" );
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) scanf("%i", &vetor[i]);
    for (int lin = 0, k = 0; lin < 3; lin++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++, k++) {
            matriz[lin][col] = vetor[k];
            printf("%i\t", matriz[lin][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TDbWsr). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/aknklqxm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/MatrixBuilding.c).

Comment: Obrigado bigown, sou iniciante na linguagem ajudou muito!